# IPP V3 customer notes not coming through

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform

I am developing an app targeting the IPP V3. My test user is set up using QuickBooks Desktop Pro 2012. I have notes for a customer in QuickBooks and I ran a sync before trying to access the data. Using the V3 customer object the notes come back as Nothing for that customer.

Are the notes stored somewhere else or are they currently not accessible using V3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer notes cannot be synced to or from QBD. 
It works with QBO. This attribute is mentioned in the 'QBO Extension' section of docs.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/customer#QBO_Extensions

Thanks